# Windows OpenSSH Match Exec string with embedded quotes

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell

Under Openssh for Windows, is there a way to specify an exec string for powershell with embedded quotes?  It's made complex by the fact that a multiword command must be quoted, and I can't figure out a way to escape the embedded quotes.  I've tried the following arguments to Match ... Exec:

```
# This gives error ${CMDVAR} is not recognized
"powershell -command ${CMDVAR}"

# This executes the script but hangs at script exit
"powershell myscript.ps1"

# This simply hangs
"powershell -command 'my long script with ^"embedded^" quotes"
```

The goal here is to exec this [nested powershell one-liner](https://superuser.com/questions/1783652/count-commandline-arguments-of-sibling-processs-ssh-on-windows):

> `if ((wmic process where "ProcessID = $((Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter ProcessId=$PID).ParentProcessId)" get commandline /value| measure-object -Word).Words -gt 2) { exit 1 }`

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this is not possible without an external script file.

The first thing to realize is that in OpenSSH, the command specified for `Match Exec` needs to be enclosed in double quotes (in the config file), since the argument to `Exec` is matched using `strdelim`:

[`readconf.c::match_cfg_line`](https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable/blob/41e17111941aa8ec97c42abe8f1006c38dd95e43/readconf.c#L664-L670)

```c
        /* All other criteria require an argument */
        if ((arg = strdelim(&cp)) == NULL ||
            *arg == '\0' || *arg == '#') {
            error("Missing Match criteria for %s", attrib);
            result = -1;
            goto out;
        }
```

and `strdelim` only accepts double quotes as delimiters:

[`misc.c::strdelim_internal`](https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable/blob/41e17111941aa8ec97c42abe8f1006c38dd95e43/misc.c#L394)

```c
#define QUOTE   "\""

/* return next token in configuration line */
static char *
strdelim_internal(char **s, int split_equals)
{
    char *old;
    int wspace = 0;

    if (*s == NULL)
        return NULL;

    old = *s;

    *s = strpbrk(*s,
        split_equals ? WHITESPACE QUOTE "=" : WHITESPACE QUOTE);
    if (*s == NULL)
        return (old);

    if (*s[0] == '\"') {
        memmove(*s, *s + 1, strlen(*s)); /* move nul too */
        /* Find matching quote */
        if ((*s = strpbrk(*s, QUOTE)) == NULL) {
            return (NULL);      /* no matching quote */
        } else {
            *s[0] = '\0';
            *s += strspn(*s + 1, WHITESPACE) + 1;
            return (old);
        }
    }
// ...
```

So, **only double quotes can be used to delimit the command**.

Then, the second thing to realize is that in OpenSSH for Windows, the command used in the `Exec` directive is executed using `system`:

[`readconf.c::execute_in_shell`](https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable/blob/41e17111941aa8ec97c42abe8f1006c38dd95e43/readconf.c#L525-L538)

```c
/*
 * Execute a command in a shell.
 * Return its exit status or -1 on abnormal exit.
 */
static int
execute_in_shell(const char *cmd)
{
    char *shell;
    pid_t pid;
    int status;

#ifdef WINDOWS
    return system(cmd);
#else
```

and thus it is executed in `cmd.exe` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/system-function?view=msvc-170). In `cmd.exe`, **you need to use double quotes to enclose arguments**, single quotes have no special meaning.

The problem is that there is no way in OpenSSH to escape the inner double quotes.

---

To go back to your examples:

```
# This gives error ${CMDVAR} is not recognized
"powershell -command ${CMDVAR}"
```

Here it's unclear what is in `CMDVAR`, and as mentioned above you would need escaped double quotes around `${CMDVAR}`, which is not possible currently with OpenSSH.

```
# This executes the script but hangs at script exit
"powershell myscript.ps1"
```

Maybe this could work with `"powershell -File myscript.ps1"` ?

```
# This simply hangs
"powershell -command 'my long script with ^"embedded^" quotes"
```

A mentioned, cmd.exe needs double quotes so the arguments to `-command` would need to be enclosed in escaped double quotes, which is not currently possible with OpenSSH.

Comment: OpenSSH bug regarding lack of inner quotes escaping: https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3474